# Loading a custom font on React Native Expo gives an error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

So I am trying to create an app with React Native Expo CLI. I have installed the blank version. I am trying to import the Open Sans typeface into my application. I have done the following steps so far:

1. Made a folder called "fonts" inside of my "assets" folder, placed the ttf file for Open Sans font inside of it.
2. Added the following code in my `App.js` file

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      fontLoaded: false
    };
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      await Font.loadAsync({
        'OpenSans': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans.ttf')
      });
      this.setState({ fontLoaded: true });
    }
    catch( error ) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Test</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
  }
});
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting an error and all the solutions that I saw on the internet didn't help me. The error which I get is the following:

```
fontFamily "OpenSans" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync.

- If you intended to use a system font, make sure you typed the name correctly and that it is supported by your device operating system.

- If this is a custom font, be sure to load it with Font.loadAsync.
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\YellowBox\YellowBox.js:59:8 in error
- node_modules\expo\build\environment\muteWarnings.fx.js:27:24 in error
- ... 24 more stack frames from framework internals
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are loading the font after the app is mounted, that why you have that error.

your render method should look something like this:

```
render() {
    if (!this.state.fontLoaded) {
        return (<View>{/*some loader*/}</View>);
    }
    return(
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Test</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
```